# Cannot use SASL if Hadoop security is not enabled

Tags: java, hadoop, kerberos, sasl, accumulo

I am trying to access accumulo secured with kerberos, this is my code snippet:

Instance inst = new ZooKeeperInstance(instanceName, zooServers);

KerberosToken kt = new KerberosToken(principal, f1,false);

Connector conn = inst.getConnector(principal, kt);

I am getting Exception as follows:

org.apache.accumulo.core.client.AccumuloException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot use SASL if Hadoop security is not enabled

at org.apache.accumulo.core.client.impl.ServerClient.execute(ServerClient.java:67)

```
at org.apache.accumulo.core.client.impl.ConnectorImpl.<init>(ConnectorImpl.java:67)
at org.apache.accumulo.core.client.ZooKeeperInstance.getConnector(ZooKeeperInstance.java:248)
at demo.prg1.AccumuloConnection.main(AccumuloConnection.java:49)
```

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot use SASL if Hadoop security is not enabled

Answer (score 0):

This is expected. Accumulo provides SASL authentication to support Kerberos, as implemented on a secure Hadoop installation. See [the documentation here](https://accumulo.apache.org/1.8/accumulo_user_manual.html#_configuring_accumulo).

Comment: I have already followed all the steps from the documentations, but i am still getting the same error

Comment: I may have misunderstood your question. It sounded like you were saying that you got this error message because Hadoop security was disabled. Are you saying that Hadoop security is actually enabled, but you are still getting the error? Have you verified that your Hadoop configuration is on your client code's class path?

Comment: Ok i got the problem, it was all about Hadoop configuration. Thanks